# How to find self intersection of this polar curve: $r = 1 + 2\cos(\theta) - 4\cos^2 (\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the values of $\theta$ where the following polar curve intersect itself:$$r = 1 + 2\cos(\theta) - 4\cos^2 (\theta).$$
I am studying this function on $[0, 2\pi] $ since it is periodic.

**My approach**
At intersection, we can say that the points $(r,\theta)$ and $ (r', \theta')$ are the same, for different values of theta, this can happen only if:

$r = r$' and $ \theta = \theta' + 2k\pi$ **or** $r = -r'$ and $ \theta = \theta' + 2k\pi + \pi $.

So I tried to replace, for the first case I get : 
$$1 + 2\cos(\theta) - 4\cos^2(\theta) = 1 + 2\cos(\theta' + 2k\pi) - 4\cos^2(\theta' + 2k\pi).$$

But since $\cos$ is $2\pi$-periodic then we get:
$$1 + 2\cos(\theta) - 4\cos^2(\theta) = 1 + 2\cos(\theta') - 4\cos^2(\theta' ).$$
Thus $\theta = \theta' + 2k\pi $ and we take $k = 0$ because the study domain is just $[0,2\pi]$ so I get that $\theta = \theta'$ and this cannot be a solution.

For the second case where I use the fact that $\cos(\theta + 2k\pi + \pi ) = -\cos(\theta)$ then I get something like 1 = 1 which is not helpful .

How would you find these points? And what is the general method to use?

Comment: For the $2$nd case:
$$r = 1 + 2\cos(\theta) - 4 \cos^2(\theta),$$
$$-r = 1 - 2\cos(\theta) - 4 \cos^2(\theta);$$
so $$1-4\cos^2(\theta)=0.$$

Comment: I used this : $$-r = 1 - 2 cos(\theta + 2k\pi + pi) + 4 cos^2(\theta)$$

Comment: Why $\color{red}{+}4\cos^2(\theta)$ ?

Comment: $- 4 \left(-\cos (\theta) \right)^2 = - 4 \cos^2 (\theta)$

Comment: Oh yes that was the problem, I didn't notice the square , thank you